# Duplicating paper multiple times in same HTML page with raphael.js

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am having an issues duplicating a Raphael drawing within the same html page. I basically will need 12 maps, each holding different data, in the same html page. My code is as follows:

**JS**

```
    var flmap = Raphael("january" ,'100%', '100%');
    flmap.setViewBox(0,0,500,500,false); 

    var keys = flmap.set();
    keys.push(flmap.path("drawing path here").attr({

parent: 'keys',
'stroke-width': '.5',
fill: '#156ba1',
stroke: "#efefef"
    }));
    keys.data({
id: 'keys',
county: 'Keys'
   })
   //There are 8 more of these var's, each drawing a region of FL, I took them out for space sake

    var flmapGroups = [keys, panhandle, south, southwest, southeast, westcentral, eastcentral, northeast, northwest];

    for (var e = 0, len = flmapGroups.length; i < len; i++) {

var el = flmapGroups[i];

el.mouseover(function() {
    this.toFront();
    this.attr({
        cursor: 'pointer',
        fill: '#f2ca54',
        stroke: '#efefef',
        'stroke-width': '.5'
    });

    this.animate({
        transform: 's1.5'
    }, 200);
    this.data({
            county: document.getElementById('county-name').innerHTML = this.data('county')
            });
});
el.mouseout(function() {
    this.animate({
        transform: 's1'
    }, 200);
    this.attr({
        fill: '#156ba1'
    });
});
     el.click(function() {
    this.animate({
        fill: '#ef882b'
    }, 200);

            this.data({
            county: document.getElementById('county-name').innerHTML = this.data('county'),
            lunar: document.getElementById('lunar').innerHTML = this.data('lunar')
            });

});


    }};
```

**HTML**

```
         <div id="january"> </div>
         <div id="county_info">
         <h1 id="county-name"></h1>
         </div>
         <div id="feb"> </div>

         <script src="js/map-jan.js"></script>
         <script src="js/map-feb.js"></script>
```

So I have 12 of the same JS files above, for each month of the year. They are all linked to the same HTML page. However, only one will load. In the HTML example I am only calling January and Feb, again for space sake. There is a bunch of blank space where you can see the others should be, but they wont load. If anyone has any advice using strictly JS I would appreciate. I had someone else look at the code and they were able to loop something using Jquery, but when Jquery was introduced there were alot more issues with different browsers and size. Any help would be appreciated and I hope this all makes sense.

Comment: Ideally I think you need to show the example on a jsfiddle to play with.

Comment: Also not really sure why you are loading multiple scripts, seems quite inefficient, for editing changes etc. One with a reasonable set of functions could make more sense. You could also put each in an immediate mode function if its a scoping issue causing the problem.